# add expiry date to pdf using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, pdf, restriction

is it possible to add an expiry date to a PDF with asp.net when someone downloads a file?

the idea is that when the user downloads a file it will be usable until a set date when it will become useless and they will have to download a fresh version.

Comment: How are you creating the PDF?

Comment: what about adding javascript to the pdf to check for a date - http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/tutorial/ch11.html

Comment: it would be an existing pdf hosted on the server. when a user requests to download it i would amend it with the expiry date for that user and send the amended file without touching the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expire dates on PDF involve Security Certificates as there is no Expire Date on a PDF File.

You can use [JS for Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html) but no matter what you do you need to hook up with [Document Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/server/documentserver/) as it's the server that sends policies and check document validation/expiration when you work with PDF Files.

for what you want, I would rather do something else that use all this technology:

- is it so important to have expiration date?
- because you don't say what is the content... if's its a book related, why not just a single file?
- or a sample data of what the user might get if he/she wants the PDF...

Comment: its a resource site that has a yearly subscription. the idea would be allow users to download content but when their subscription runs out they need to come back to the site.

Comment: you should not treat your clients like that, content that they have access to download for that period should be theirs after download. New content need new subscription. This is valid anywhere... don't try to swim the other way around, your clients could not forgive you for that!